# Regex.IsMatch gives true but http://www.regexr.com/ gives false

Tags: c#

I'm trying to check if the next string is match to this pattern in this code:

```
string str = "CRSSA.T,";
var pattern = @"((\w+\.{1}\w+)+(,\w+\.{1}\w+)*)";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern));
```

the site: http://www.regexr.com/ says it's not match(everything match, except the last comma), but that code prints True. is it possible?

thanks ahead! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sure it can happen that different regex engines disagree, either because the capabilities differ or the interpretation, e.g. Java's `String.matches` method explicitly requires the *whole* string to match, not just a substring.

In your case, though, both regexr and .NET say it matches, because the substring `CRSSA.T` will match. Your third group, containing the comma, has a `*` quantifier, i.e. it can be matched zero or more times. In this case it's being matched zero times, but that's okay. It's still a match.

If you want the whole string to match, and no substrings whatsoever, then you need to add anchors to your regex:

```
^((\w+\.{1}\w+)+(,\w+\.{1}\w+)*)$
```

Furthermore, `{1}` is a useless quantifier, you can just leave it out. Also, if you have a capturing group around the whole regex, you can leave that out as well, as it's already in capturing group 0 automatically. So a bit simplified you could use:

```
^(\w+\.\w+)+(,\w+\.\w+)*$
```

Also be careful with `\w` and `\b`. Those two features are closely linked (by the definition of `\w` and `\W` and are not always intuitive. E.g. they include the underscore and, depending on the regex engine, a lot more than just `[A-Za-z_]`, e.g. in .NET `\w` also matches things like `ä`, `µ`, `Ð`, `ª`, or `º`. For those reasons I tend to be rather explicit when writing more robust regexes (i.e. those that are not just used for a quick one-off usage) and use things like `[A-Za-z]`, `\p{L}`, `(?=\P{L}|$)`, etc. instead of `\w`, `\W` and `\b`.

Comment: thanks you! is it enough that a single substring will match and IsMatch method returns true? and in this case, is there any way to check only about the whole string and not also on parts of it?